# SQLite dblink to Oracle possible?

Tags: oracle, sqlite

I have a SQLite database and I need to connect to an Oracle database so I can do some reports.

So my questions are:

1. Is it possible to create a dblink from SQLite to the Oracle database, so that I can use something like:

   ```
   select *
     from sqlitetable s
     join oracletable@oracleserver o on o.column = s.column
    where s.column = 'x'
   ```
2. Assuming this is indeed possible, do I need to have some setup/support from the oracle admin, or can I simply connect via my existing account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is, in theory, possible to write a [virtual table](http://www.sqlite.org/vtab.html) that links to Oracle.
However, I don't know of any actual implementation.

Comment: Yeah, looks like it might be usable for this purpose, but this would be more like a longer project, assuming there is no ready made plugin and it has to be implemented by myself. Maybe I take this on, but for now I would need something more immediate. :)